# Html.DisplayFor in mvc webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using an asp.net mvc webgrid, is it possible to render a column using Html.DisplayFor for the current row/column?

```
    grid.Column("Roller", "Roller", canSort: true, format: @<text>@Html.DisplayFor( <the row result here> )</text>)
```

The Html.DisplayFor(m) helper uses the page model, not the current row item. Is there a way around this.

Thanks

// Johan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For an example, consider you are binding a list of `Banner` objects to your WebGrid. Also consider the `Banner.Active` property, which is a `boolean` value that you want to be rendered as a CheckBox. You can do this:

```
format: (item) => { var banner = item.Value as Banner;
                    return Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => banner.Active); 
                   }
```

You could also do this:

```
format: (item) => Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ((item as WebGridRow).Value as Banner).Active)
```

But I would consider the first option more readable.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
```

than do

```
grid.Column("Roller", "Roller", canSort: true, format: @<text>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.blabla)</text>)
```

Using item.blabla"whatever ur item name is" may work but im not really experienced about this.

also there is not much difference between

```
@<text>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.blabla)</text>
```

&

```
@<text>@item.blabla</text>
```

both usage does the job.

Comment: There is if you have display attributes being applied to the property or model

Comment: @m.t.bennett yep you'r right, it's a minor change thats not easily seen.